# MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED not called if the install was programmatic

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, runtime.exec

I am trying to restart my app after it installation. I made a receiver of MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED action. And i starting the app from there programatically:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "am start io.my.package/io.my.package.MainActivity"});
```

When i doing the install from the terminal with the following command everything working fine:

```
adb install -r /Users/ ... /app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

But when i do it from the code programatically like this:

```
command = "pm install -r /mnt/sdcard/Download/app-debug.apk"
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", command});
```

The receiver don't get the action...
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The problem was not the programmatic part of the process. I guess i missed something in my tests.

The real problem is that i don't get the action when i change the version number. When i don't change the version everything works fine. Very strange.